# How to convert Web Stream to NodeJS native Stream

Tags: node.js, file, node-streams

I am taking file input from user as

```
<input type="file"/>
```

It returns file object has Blob. This object has a method `.stream()` which returns `ReadableStream`. Now, i want to pass this stream to [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamArray) library. But it takes NodeJS native stream - `Readable`.
Now, how do i convert the `ReadableStream` (webstream) to `Readable` (node stream) ?

Comment: "This object has a method .stream()"  what is "this" object?! Post more info, complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Node has an helper function:

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options

Another more complex way is to implement a node stream that consumes the web stream.