# Reading csv file from s3 into ExcelJS Workbook

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, exceljs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to do some operations on a csv file saved in s3 using exceljs library in my aws lambda. I am not able to initialize the exceljs Workbook object with the response returned by aws-sdk. As I explain below, the issue is mainly that the sdk gives stream of the *MDN* form whereas exceljs requires nodejs type of stream.

The sdk response is like this 
`const data: GetObjectCommandOutput = await s3Client.send(command)`

`data.Body` is of type  `SdkStream<Readable | ReadableStream<any> | Blob | undefined> | undefined`
Here `ReadableStream<any>` is the MDN kind of stream.

I tried to create a nodejs stream like this(ignoring null check for now)
`const readableStream: ReadableStream = data.Body!.transformToWebStream();`

```
const expectedNodejsStream = new Readable().wrap(readableStream);
```

But seems the issue here is `wrap` works for **NodeJS**.ReadableStream.

I also tried this as suggested in many answers

```
const nodeStream = new stream.Writable();
(data.Body!as Readable).pipe(nodeStream);
```

But an exception is thrown as data.Body does not get typecasted to Readable during runtime.

Exceljs constructor looks like this

```
const wb = new Excel.Workbook();
wb.xlsx.read(nodeStream);//doesnt work
```

or like this

```
new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader(data.Body!.transformToWebStream());//does not work
```

Is it possible to create the excel workbook from sdk response data without having to convert the MDN stream to nodejs stream? If no, is there a way to do this conversion without implementing our own stream as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509505/how-to-convert-web-stream-to-nodejs-native-stream)

aws-sdk/client-s3 v^3.121
aws-sdk v2.1158

Comment: please excuse csv and xlsx mixup...
its not related to the problem

Comment: I know a workaround is to save the file temporarily into filesystem and then read but I want to initalise directly from the sdk response

Answer (score 0):

`data.Body` can be typecasted to `Buffer` which is a nodejs construct. We can create a nodejs Readable stream from this buffer.

```
const data = await s3Client2.getObject(bucketParams).promise();
  console.log(`data: GetObjectCommandOutput`);
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data.Body as Buffer);

  const wb = new Excel.Workbook();
  wb.csv.read(Readable.from(dataBuffer));
```